# Detect if content on FixedPage exceeds bottom boundary

Tags: c#, wpf, fixeddocument, fixedpage

I'm creating a document I'd like to print later. This document shall contain a grid that lists items like a table, including a header row. The number of items varies and therefore it is possible that the grid exceeds the bottom boundary of a single page. When that happens, I'd like to continue on a second page, the "table" header shall be on it again. I 'm adding the rows programatically in a for-loop.

Do you know a way how to detect if the bottom page boundary is exceeded? Maybe there's a different approach.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution is to take a StackPanel as the "root child" for each FixedPage. I then can add content and measure it.

```
public StackPanel AddNewPage()
{
    PageContent pC = new PageContent();
    FixedPage fP = new FixedPage { Width = PageWidth, Height = PageHeight, Margin = Margin };

    StackPanel sP = new StackPanel { Width = PageWidth - Margin.Left - Margin.Right };
    fP.Children.Add(sP);

    pC.Child = fP;

    //FixedDocument
    Document.Pages.Add(pC);

    //used later to add content to the page 
    return sP;
}

public bool IsPageOverfilled(int pageIndex)
{
    StackPanel sP = (Document.Pages[pageIndex].Child as FixedPage).Children[0] as StackPanel;
    //necessary to recognize new added elements
    sP.UpdateLayout();
    sP.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));

    if (sP.DesiredSize.Height > MaxPageContentHeight)
        return true;
    else return false;
}
```

MaxPageContentHeight is defined as the following:

```
double MaxPageContentHeight = PageHeight - Margin.Top - Margin.Bottom;
```